# toggle between data and markline in echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

Given the scatter series with markline in echarts as below :

```
option = {
    xAxis: {},
    yAxis: {},
    series: [{
        symbolSize: 20,
        data: [
            [10.0, 8.04],
            [8.0, 6.95],
            [13.0, 7.58],
            [9.0, 8.81],
            [11.0, 8.33],
            [14.0, 9.96],
            [6.0, 7.24],
            [4.0, 4.26],
            [12.0, 10.84],
            [7.0, 4.82],
            [5.0, 5.68]
        ],
        type: 'scatter',
        markLine: {
            data: [
                {name: 'average',
                type: 'average',
                valueIndex: 0}
            ]
        }
    }]
};
```

I wanted to toggle between data and markline. Lets say when markline off , only scattered data should be shown. And when markline on only markline should be shown in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work when you simply set the e-chart option accordingly:

- when you only want to show the markline, set the [symbol](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.data.symbol) for each data-item to `none`
- when you only want to show the data, `markLine` can be `undefined` (or set [symbol](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.markLine.data.0.symbol) for each markline to `none`)